# Не отображаются формы Django на странице

Tags: html, django, forms

Уже долго вожусь с данной проблемой, нигде не смог найти решение. чувствую, что ответ на поверхности, надеюсь тут помогут... Собственно проблема в том, что не могу передать form в html, он её просто не видет.
Вот файл views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import ContactForm

def main_page_en(request):
    return render(request, 'portfolio/main_page_en.html')

def main_page_rus(request):
    return render(request, 'portfolio/main_page_rus.html')

def my_works(request):
    return render(request, 'portfolio/works.html')

def contact_us(request):
    return render(request, 'portfolio/contact_us.html')




def contact_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            messages.success(request, f'Спасибо, {name}! Я свяжусь с Вами в ближайшее время')
            return redirect('main-page-rus')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    template_name = 'portfolio/contact_us.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Вот models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.EmailField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'content', 'price', 'phonenumber']
```

Вот forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'content', 'phonenumber', 'price']
```

Сам HTML:

```
{% extends 'portfolio/base.html'%}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action=".">
    {{ form|crispy }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main_page_rus, name = 'main-page-rus'),
    path('en', views.main_page_en, name = 'main-page-en'),
    path('works', views.my_works, name = 'my-works'),
    path('contact', views.contact_us, name = 'contact-us'),
]
```

Помогите новичку, скорее всего слона то и не вижу. Спасибо!

P.S. Если укажете и на другие ошибки, то буду очень признателен.

Comment: Покажите urls.py и ссылку которую открываете в браузере

Comment: csrf token добавьте в форму. Шаблон тот вообще? В функцию заходит?

Comment: Да, про csrf забыл в этот раз, но до этого его использовал и было тоже самое, видимо сейчас нечаино удалил при редактированиию

Comment: Вроде всё правильно, шаблон тот, urls.py добавил для большей ясности. Ссылка у меня такая: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact:

Comment: В urls.py у вас прописана функция contact_us, но в функции contact_us у вас не существует никакого form, вот и не работает. Функция contact_form нигде никак не используется, будьте внимательнее

Comment: Да, вы правы. Спасибо большое! Вот сколько времени можно потерять из-за банальной невнимательности. Спасибо!